# Linear linearly time varying systems Laplace transform

Tags: linear-systems, laplace-transform

Suppose that for a system $S$ if we have $t_{2} = t_{1}+t_{0}\rightarrow h(t,t_{2}) =h(t,t_{1})+h(t,t_{0}) $ .Then if we take the double Laplace transform to$t,t_{2}$ we will get:

$$L_{t_{2}}(L_{t}(h(t,t_{2})) = L_{t_{2}}(L_{t}(h(t,t_{1}))+L_{t_{2}}(L_{t}(h(t,t_{0})).$$
But
\begin{align*}
t_{2} &= t_{1}+t_{0}\\
&\rightarrow \\
L_{t_{2}}(L_{t}(h(t,t_{2})) &= L_{t_{1}+t_{0}}(L_{t}(h(t,t_{2}))\\
&\rightarrow\\
 L_{t_{2}}(L_{t}(h(t,t_{2})) &= L_{t_{0}+t_{1}}(L_{t}(h(t,t_{0}))+L_{t_{1}+t_{0}}(L_{t}(h(t,t_{1})),
\end{align*} but the Laplace operator is a linear operator which means

\begin{align*}
L_{t_{0}+t_{1}}(L_{t}(h(t,t_{0})) &= L_{t_{0}}(L_{t}(h(t,t_{0}))+L_{t_{1}}(L_{t}(h(t,t_{0}))\\
\text{and}\\
L_{t_{0}+t_{1}}(L_{t}(h(t,t_{1})) &= L_{t_{0}}(L_{t}(h(t,t_{1}))+L_{t_{1}}(L_{t}(h(t,t_{1})),
\end{align*}
but $t_{0}$ and  $ t_{1}$ are independent variables which means that $L_{t_{0}}(L_{t}(h(t,t_{1})) = 0$ and $L_{t_{1}}(L_{t}(h(t,t_{0})) =0$.

So we are left with:

\begin{align*}
L_{t_{2}}(L_{t}(h(t,t_{2})) &= L_{t_{1}}(L_{t}(h(t,t_{1}))+L_{t_{0}}(L_{t}(h(t,t_{0}))\\
\rightarrow \\
H(s,s_{2}) &= H(s,s_{1})+H(s,s_{0})
\end{align*}

Is that correct?